# Centered responive hero text in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/3ffjn3sm/1/

It's a hero image/background with a h1 heading on the top.

The text needs to be centered and have a max-width but shrink when the window is resized.

This is works perfect on mac browsers but on ie 8-11 the text and play glyph aren't centered.

I'm using bootstrap and the play glyph will start a movie.

I'm only testing in browser emulators, can anyone confirm the text isn't centred and how I can do this in ie.

```
<div class="hero">

    <div class="hero_heading text-center">
        <h1>This is the hero heading This is the hero heading</h1>

        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3ffjn3sm/3/)**

just add `width: 100%` along with `max-width: 600px;` for IE to recognize the max-width

```
.hero_heading{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 20px; right: 0;
    margin:auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 100%; /* add this */
}
```

[image]